# ImageView.image = nil crashing after app hibernated/resumed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, uiimageview, uiimage

One of the views in my app has a method to set it's 'default' layout - `setDefaultView`. In this method, I loop through the subViews, and if one is an ImageView, it sets the image to nil.

This works fine when my app is initially launched from XCode. But, when I hibernate my app by pressing the home button, then go back into the app and trigger `setDefaultView`, it crashes in this method where the images are set to nil.

Any suggestions on what may be going wrong here?

Source code:

```
-(void)setDefaultView {

// Hide all equals labels and images; set all images to nil
for (UIView *view in [secondScrollerView subviews]) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;

        if ([label.text isEqualToString:@"="]) {
            label.hidden = YES;
        }
    }

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {

        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)view;
        imageView.hidden = YES;

        imageView.image = nil;    // Crashes here
    }
}

// do other stuff here...
}
```

Comment: Please, post code where you set `image` to `imageView`

Comment: Nekto - your comment was enough for me to find the issue.

I was releasing the UIImage even though it was never allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probable is that you set the `imageView.image` to an autoreleased object.  The `imageView.image = nil;` line will release the old image, which will be a problem if it is already released.

Comment: Thanks - I had manually released it. Found the bug after Nekto's comment on my original question.